# Concatenating SQL row values into a summary field

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have customers that can belong to many groups at the same time. I need to create super-groups out of the distinct groups, in alphabetical order.

```
Cust_ID|Group
1      |Group 4
1      |Group 6
1      |Group 6
1      |Group 6
1      |Group 5
2      |Group 3
2      |Group 1
2      |Group 3
```

Desired outcome is

```
Cust_ID|Supergroup
1      |Group 4, Group 5, Group 6
2      |Group 1, Group 3
```

What I have tried

1. STRING_AGG
   STRING_AGG - not available in my SQL server version (I'm using 2016)
2. FOR XML PATH
   It's a bit hacky, but I've managed to get concatenation of all records in one field.

   ```
   Select SUBSTRING( 
   ( 
        SELECT top 15 PolicyOwner1_CISKey, ',' + clientGroup AS 'data()'
            FROM IND_IN_SCOPE FOR XML PATH('') ), 2 , 9999) As Groups
   ```
3. PIVOT
   From my reading, it only seems to handle numerics, it's strings I'm needing to be aggregated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use right `FOR XML PATH` and `DISTINCT` subquery.

```
SELECT 
  [Cust_ID],
  STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + [Group] 
    FROM IND_IN_SCOPE
    WHERE (Cust_ID = t1.Cust_ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Supergroup
FROM IND_IN_SCOPE t1
GROUP BY Cust_ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0dc1b8eb2fe2a3c96b6d07ea3536961a)

Comment: Ripper! Works beautifully.